# Multitasking selenium to scrape data instantly to reduce time complexity python (Asynchronous Tasking)

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, python-multithreading, multitasking

Below given is a sample program to call selenium process again and again. please help me to learn how can i perform multiprocessing/multithreading (multitasking).

```
urls= [consider 10 urls]
def selenium(urls)
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities = dcap,service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--load-images=false'])
    driver.get(url)
    some_process()

for i in urls:
    selenium(i)
```

> Task here is to run all the given urls in one shot at same time with different background panthomjs browsers
>   **Asynchronous processing of links.**

Comment: I had similar task lately. I created couple threads and each thread were running browser instance. You can also use some unit testing libraries functionality to run tests in parallel. In Java world we have TestNG which can do parallel execution.

Comment: you can use Multi threading. You can see a similar example : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python)